# (JS) Google Script App Search / Filter for keyword

Tags: javascript, json, excel, google-apps-script

I have been stumped on this for a while. I am fairly new to Google script app and wanted to see if there is a way to make this happen. So far, I've used a few methods within Google Sheet but seem to not get it working.

The code below does give me an output of all the data, however, the data that is nested in the `data.custom_fields[x]` has multiple objects that is separated by ",". I would like to be able to filter out the other key words and just use whatever is inside `"display_value="`. The `display_value=` is not always in the same area so have to run a search for them.

I am assuming some kind of If statement would be used here..

An example of the object is:

```
{type=x, resource_subtype=x, created_by={name=x, gid=x, resource_type=x}, display_value=Cool Value, description=x, enabled=x, resource_type=custom_field, gid=x, enum_options=[x.lang.Object;x, enum_value={x}, name=x}
```

I've tried to `split` function as well but not sure how to filter out the words I need.

```
function Users() {
  var options = {
   "headers" : {
     "Authorization": "API Key here"
   }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL here", options);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tab Name here"); // specific sheet name getSheetByName(""); alternatively use ss.getActiveSheet()

  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll.data; // "data" is the key containing the relevant objects
  var rows = [],
    data;
  
  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet[i];
  rows.push([
    data.gid,
    data.name, 
    data.permalink_url,
    data.due_on,
    data.custom_fields[1],
    data.custom_fields[2],
    data.custom_fields[4],
    data.custom_fields[5],
    data.custom_fields[6],
    data.custom_fields[7],
    data.custom_fields[8],
    data.custom_fields[9],
    
    ]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  // [row to start on], [column to start on], [number of rows], [number of entities]
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 12);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
```

Thank you in advance!

[Example Image of JSON imported data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY3dQ.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample value of `response.getContentText()` and your expected situation as an image?

Comment: Hi there, logger.log(dataAll) shows the whole output like the example above. So the question is it possible to filter out the example object that is nested in one cell to just have `"display_value="`? or the content that is after `"display_value="` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, when you show the value of `response.getContentText()` of `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL here", options);`, `logger log of data.All is a reference error`. Is my understanding correct? And from `So the question is it possible to filter out the example object that is nested in one cell to just have "display_value="? or the content that is after "display_value=" ?`, I cannot still underatand your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Sorry, I had a little error that I corrected above. logger.log does not have an error. It does give the whole output like the example in the original post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot add any images because the rating is still too low. I did embed the image above though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although they appear separated by `,`'s, that is only how they're displayed in the log. Because you're using `JSON.parse`, you're receiving/converting to an Object, not a string.

Because `data.custom_fields` is an array of objects, you can access the property/key values as : `data.custom_fields[x].display_value`.

Learn More:

- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [Accessing Object Properties](https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract display_value, try

```
let myVal = myData.match(/(?<=display_value=)[^,]+/g)[0]
```

I guess that myData could be data.custom_fields[5], so replace it by

```
data.custom_fields[5].match(/(?<=display_value=)[^,]+/g)[0]
```